# Parsing a complex string into sets of integers in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm a beginner programmer and I was tasked an assignment to calculate total money spent on phone calls, a String of phone numbers and call time. Making calculations is easy for me however parsing the string itself is quite challenging. I need to convert a String containing semicolons, commas and newlines into sets of phone numbers and total call time which are integers. The string looks like this:

```
hh:mm:ss,nnn-nnn-nnn
hh:mm:ss,nnn-nnn-nnn
hh:mm:ss,nnn-nnn-nnn
```

I know that I would be able to parse by line if I was reading a text file using scanner and a `hasNext` function, so should I utilize `\n` somehow? Using the `split(":")` would not get me very far.

Any other things that can be helpful? 
Any help or useful information would be appreciated!

Comment: Split on comma to separate time from phone number, then use some date/time library classes to parse the time for you - tons of examples are available for doing that part.

Comment: Look into [StringTokenizer](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=Java+stringtokenizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just perform multiple splits, first to separate the time from the phone number, then to separate the individual parts of each. For example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStr);

while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String parts[] = line.split(",");
    String time[] = parts[0].split(":");
    String phone[] = parts[1].split("-");
    // Process the time and phone number here
}
```

The variable parts has two elements, the time and the phone number. The variable time contains the three elements of the time, and phone contains the three elements of the phone number.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function and just specify every token to split at with `"[]"`
for example use `split("[ ,:-]")`

the code

```
String number = "11:22:33,444-555-666";
String[] numbers = number.split("[ ,:-]");
for (String temp: numbers){
System.out.println(temp);
```

Gives the result

> 11
>   22
>   33
>   444
>   555
>   666

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Regular Expressions and Pattern/Matcher for this type of task:

```
        private static final String REGEX =
        "..:..:..,...-...-...";

    private static final String INPUT = "h1:m1:s1,nnn-nnn-nnn   \n"
            + "   h2:m2:s2,nnn-nnn-nnn   \n"
            + " hh:mm:ss,nnn-nnn-nnn";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
       Matcher matcher = p.matcher(INPUT);
       while(matcher.find()) {
           String timePhoneNumber = matcher.group(0);
           String tokens[] = timePhoneNumber.split(",");
           String time = tokens[0];
           String phoneNumber = tokens[1];
           System.out.println("Time="+time+"; phone="+phoneNumber);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MultiSplit {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String INPUT = "14:23:51,n11-n12-n13   \n"//
                + "   15:24:46,n21-n22-n23   \n" //
                + "   15:2a:46,n21-n22-n23   \n" // error
                + "\n" // error
                + "null\n" // error
                + " 12:11:10,n31-n32n33  \n" // error
                + " 12:1111,n31-n32n33  \n" // error
                + " 12:11:12,n31-n32-n33\n";

        final String[] dirtyLines = INPUT.split("\n");

        System.out.println("MODE 1");
        for (final String dirtyLine : dirtyLines) {
            try {
                final String cleanLine = dirtyLine.trim();
                final String line = cleanLine.replace(",", ":");
                final String[] parts = line.split(":");

                final int hour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                final int minute = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                final int second = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                final String phone = parts[3];
                System.out.println("h:" + hour + "\tm:" + minute + "\ts:" + second + " \t => " + phone);

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error on line <" + dirtyLine + ">: " + e);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nMODE 2");
        for (final String dirtyLine : dirtyLines) {
            try {
                final String cleanLine = dirtyLine.trim();
                final String line = cleanLine.replace(",", ":").replace("-", ":");
                final String[] parts = line.split(":");

                final int hour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                final int minute = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                final int second = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
                final String phone1 = parts[3];
                final String phone2 = parts[4];
                final String phone3 = parts[5];
                System.out.println("h:" + hour + "\tm:" + minute + "\ts:" + second + " \t => " + phone1 + "#" + phone2 + "#" + phone3);

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error on line <" + dirtyLine + ">: " + e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```